# How effective are acoustic panels to deaden a room?

Tags: drums, sound, acoustics

I need to deaden an echoing drum practice room and am considering acoustic panels, probably DIY ones 3.5" deep filled with rock wool.  I'm look at these vs. heavy blankets for aesthetic reasons.  I'd like to know they are effective before I spend the labor to assemble them.  Also interested in how many (or how much area of wall) I need.  My space is small, about 10' x 10'.

Comment: Good panels can be _very_ effective, but it depends on rather too many factors to discuss it on StackExchange. Room acoustics is a really tricky science.

Comment: I might be able to give a better answer if I knew whether you wish to remove room reverberation or eliminate sound transfer to surrounding rooms.

Comment: I'm just trying to dead the room, i.e. remove the echo and reverberation.  I understand that soundproofing is a whole different animal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question mostly because it's not on a [topic covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Treating room acoustics is certainly tangentially important to musical practice, but it's a separate topic (and installation tips are definitely off-topic). Also partly because "does it work well" is too vague/subjective for good answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the *sound absorption coefficients* for the materials you are considering to see how dead different amounts of materials will make your room.

Here is a chart: http://www.acoustic.ua/st/web_absorption_data_eng.pdf

What you could do is approximate the room response by simplifying the math by assuming the non-damped surface area reflects 100% of the sound equally (i.e. treat the walls as if they are a sphere with the drum kit in the center). Then multiply the absorption coefficient by the percent of surface area you intend to cover with the material and estimate that the intensity of the reflections will be that much less. For example, if you cover 50% of the surfaces with materials having absorption coefficients of 0.50, then you could estimate that reflections and reverb will be reduced by about 25%.

Two important reminders: the ceiling and floor count as reflective surfaces for your estimates, and absorbing reflections only affects the reverberant sound level in the room. It does not affect the direct sound level (from the drums to anyone’s ears), nor does it necessarily reduce the amount of sound transmitted to other rooms through the walls of the room. In other words, you can’t really make the drums quieter this way, only deader. And you don’t want it too dead because that would sound weird.

Really a good way to go is to plan to build perhaps four panels and put them up and see if you’re happy. If not, build four more. Keep going until it sounds good. It’s not often effective to do math to predict how something will sound.

Comment: It should be stated clearly that there is a balance point between to much reverberation and not enough reverberation and the goal is to find that balance point. Ask a lot of questions and be ready to experiment.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I've never experienced "too dead".  The room was just fine when it doubled as a storage room full of shelves of junk.  Now that I've cleaned it out, I can hardly stand to play due to the echo.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to tame a 10' x 10' box which you intend to be LOUD in.

You might be well advised to forget the aesthetics and put most of the junk back, leaving JUST room for the drum kit!  Then you get free sound treatment AND free storage!  I've too often seen people ruin a perfectly useable room with 'design'.

Answer (score 0):

Although, it's an old thread but I want to share that acoustic panels really works very well in deaden the room. My apartment was very close to the main city road and it was a quite annoying situation for me almost all day because of traffic sounds. I will say that after installing these [acoustic felt panels](https://www.acousticsolutions.com/echotrol-acoustic-panels) in my apartment, I was like that staying in pin drop silent room. :-

Comment: I'm confused by the down-vote. If people feel the original question should be off-topic, maybe it should be closed. Meanwhile, although this answer mentions a different material than the OP proposed, it seems like a reasonable answer to the question.

Comment: @AndyBonner - this answer addresses the *external* noise problem, which is different from the echo OP is asking about. It's a good solution, maybe, but to a different problem!